# Setting AllowGuestsToAccessGroups via graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to add AllowGuestsToAccessGroups to a group. I can set following with no problems:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/f051a482-7bb8-417c-83be-xxxx/settings
>   {'displayName':'Group.Unified.Guest','templateId':
>   '08d542b9-071f-4e16-94b0-74abb372e3d9','values':[{'name':
>   'AllowToAddGuests','value': 'false'}]}'}

However this throws an error ('Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)'):
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/f051a482-7bb8-417c-83be-xxx/settings
{'displayName':'Group.Unified','templateId': '62375ab9-6b52-47ed-826b-58e47e0e304b','values':[{'name': 'AllowGuestsToAccessGroups','value': 'false'}]}'}

It seems like the same permissions are required any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to update the "AllowGuestsToAccessGroups" property through Microsoft Graph currently.  The endpoint for [Update Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) contains a list of properties that are updateable but this property is not in the list.  I tested through Graph Explorer and received similar errors.

As an alternative you can update through the AzureADPreview module using a script similar to the following:

```
$groupTemplate = Get-AzureADDirectorySettingTemplate -id 08d542b9-071f-4e16-94b0-74abb372e3d9
$settingCopy = $groupTemplate.CreateDirectorySetting()
$settingCopy["AllowToAddGuests"] = $false

$gp = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "<groupDisplayName>"

New-AzureADObjectSetting -TargetType Groups -TargetObjectId $gp.ObjectId -DirectorySetting $settingCopy 

Get-AzureADObjectSetting -TargetType Groups -TargetObjectId $gp.ObjectId | Select-Object -ExpandProperty values
```